Get type of members of struct passed to a template
Essentially I've been curious as to how much I can use templates:
Suppose I have two structs that have no member in common
struct A{
  int k;
  char l;
  std::string s;
};

struct B{
  long h;
  float r;
};

I want to write a template S that should be something like
T<A, 5>
/* contains one std::array<int, 5> called k,
one std::array<char, 5> called l
and one std::array<std::string, 5> called s */

T<B, 3>
/* contains one std::array<long, 3> named h
and one std::array<float, 3> called r */

The main hurdle that I'm encountering is that I can't really get out of a struct the types that compose it, is there any way to get over this problem?
I don't have much experience in using templates beyond the basic stuff so please try to explain keeping this in mind

You should not define a struct with named members but you can use std::tuple with the data types you need and expand later for your purpose. Accessing types of a struct will hopefully be available if reflection TS will be part of C++.... we are waiting decades for it :-)

templates do not help much for that. What you ask for requires reflection which c++ does not have (only very limited)

Out of curiosity: why do you want the output to mention std::arrays where your structs contain none ?

is there are real problem your are trying to solve or is this mainly supposed to be an exercise on templates? If it is the latter, you can give up on the member names and use tuples as Klaus suggested. If it is the former, and you are set for the member names, I'd use some code generation (outside of c++)

@wohlstad simpler for of the question is to write a template T that for a given struct S { int x;} has an instantiation struct T<S,42> { std::array<int,42> x; }. Its not about generating output on the console, but about array-ifying members of structrs

I found this: https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/4yp7fv/c17_structured_bindings_convert_struct_to_a_tuple/ and https://godbolt.org/z/c71oe6znf. Does this help?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai got it, now this makes sense.

@wohlstad array of structs vs struct of arrays stuff

@Klaus thanks, would there be any way to make that tuple not allocated in memory in a way guaranteed by standard?

@Phoe87 thanks, it's clear now. At first I thought you are only interested in reflection in order to ispect (and print) the types of members in a given struct.

@joergbrech tbh idk, I don't get it, I still have to get comfortable with rvalue references, thanks anyways

to make that tuple not allocated in memory  A tuple as a template parameter is a type and not an instance. As this it will not allocate any memory during runtime.

There is no way to do that currently in C++. There is a proposal on-track for C++26 to add facilities that would let you do that. The proposal includes your case as an example.

Thanks, is there any actual chance that this proposal gets accepted in the standard? I'm asking you because you certainly know more about proposals than me as I know basically nothing about it

@Phoe87 It is apparently on-track for being included in C++26. The committee want this feature, they are in the process of deciding the exact wording to standardise.

One important thing to note is that the difference between a POD struct
struct A
  int k;
  char l;
  std::string s;
}

and an std::tuple<int, char, std::string> is that the POD struct A has names k, l and s associated with its elements. As others already pointed out, handling named elements is not possible at the moment, but there is a proposal to add reflection capabilities to C++.
So the best you can achieve now is to have a function, that returns a tuple of arrays, i.e. for A this would be
std::tuple<
   std::array<int, 5>
   std::array<char, 5>
   std::array<std::string, 5>
>;

If you know the types in A, this is easy:
template <std::size_t Size, typename... Ts>
auto create_arrays() noexcept {
    return std::tuple<std::array<Ts, Size>...>();
}

The only piece missing is how you would extract the types from A. The link https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/4yp7fv/c17_structured_bindings_convert_struct_to_a_tuple/ provides a function to_tuple, that converts a POD type to a tuple. We can then extract the types held by this tuple (Note that the to_tuple function in this example only supports POD types with up to four elements. This can be extended to another number of course).
namespace details {
    template <std::size_t Size, typename... Ts>
    auto create_arrays_impl(std::tuple<Ts...>&&) noexcept {
        return create_arrays<Size, Ts...>();
    }
}

template <std::size_t Size, typename T>
auto create_arrays(T&& object) noexcept {
    using type = std::decay_t<T>;
    using tuple = std::invoke_result_t<decltype(&to_tuple<type>), type>;
    return details::create_arrays_impl<Size>(to_tuple(object));
}

// This is the tuple of arrays you are looking for:
template <std::size_t Size, typename S>
using T = std::invoke_result_t<decltype(&create_arrays<Size, S>), S>;

Here is a full code example: https://godbolt.org/z/v6ofTf379

Assuming some esoteric practices like declaring a struct as a tuple of elements and an enum that describes names could it be possible to assign the names by taking the corresponding enum?

I don't think there is.

not even using an "identity macro"? Lemme clarify, idk anymore what I'm talking about, I'm grasping for straws

Can you elaborate why the names of the elements are so important to you? How would you want to use them? What is it, that you can only do if you know the element names?

Intuitive access to the elements and a bit of curiosity in pushing the limits

Ok. There might be some C++ voodoo to get you close without reflection, who knows. But I would bet that even if there was, it would be horrible unmaintainable code for a bit of simplified access to the elements. So I think your best bet is to either wait for reflection TS to land, or live with unnamed arrays in a tuple.
